# How to allow only unique row data using sequalize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I wanted unique row data entry only in my table. For example:

> Requirement_id , Resource_id , User_id are the columns. if the data to enter into those columns are not unique with respect to that row, then it shouldn't allow entering that data.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
const BookmarkTbs = sequelize.define("BookmarkTbs", {
  Bookmark_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  Requirement_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: true,
    references: { 
      model: 'RequirementsTbs',
      key: 'Requirement_id'
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE', 
  },
  Resource_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: true,
    references: { 
      model: 'ResourceTbs',
      key: 'Resource_id'
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE', 
  } , 
  User_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: { 
      model: 'UsersTbs',
      key: 'User_id'
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE', 
  }
});

return BookmarkTbs;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in sequelize that you can use when declaring columns in models called "unique" by default it is set to false. When set to true, and duplicate data is entered into that column you get an error along the lines of "blank already exists in table" (Forgot the exact error message).

Example:

```
module.exports = User = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        ...
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true
        },
        ...
    })
    return User
}
```

Here if a user tries to register with a email that is already in use, you'll get an error which you can catch and send the user back a http 409 status with an appropriate error message.